Internet speed from AWS Singapore region to EU is very slow
We are running k8s cluster in AWS Singapure region. We also have self-managed EC2 NAT instance of type t3.xlarge. According to spec, it has 1 Gbps baseline speed, and burst up to 5 Gbps.
When running speedtest on the instance, I'm seeing 1gbps for download and upload. However, real speed is very different when I'm trying to download a file from server in EU.  Downloading a test file from hetzner (https://hel1-speed.hetzner.com) shows around 100mbps.
At the same time, Network in (bytes) chart in AWS is showing 1gbps.
Why are we losing so much speed? I understand that there is latency between regions, but it shouldn't be that large? mtr is showing large packets loss:
13. if-ae-41-2.tcore2.svw-singapore.as6453.net                                                                     72.4%    30  200.5 202.4 199.4 215.0   5.2
14. if-ae-33-2.tcore2.svw-singapore.as6453.net                                                                     86.2%    30  180.5 180.7 180.4 181.2   0.4
15. (waiting for reply)
16. if-ae-36-7.tcore1.av3-toyohashi.as6453.net                                                                     65.5%    30  201.8 201.4 200.7 203.0   0.7
17. if-ae-2-2.tcore2.av3-toyohashi.as6453.net                                                                      72.4%    30  193.3 193.4 192.9 194.2   0.3
18. (waiting for reply)
19. if-bundle-34-2.qcore2.lvw-losangeles.as6453.net                                                                73.3%    30  202.1 202.4 201.9 202.9   0.4
20. if-bundle-2-2.qcore1.lvw-losangeles.as6453.net                                                                 60.0%    30  199.2 199.2 198.8 200.1   0.4
21. ash-speed.hetzner.com                                                                                          60.0%    30  253.0 255.0 252.6 268.5   4.7

I would appriciate any suggestions on where else I can look to solve this.

The carrier(s) are oversubscribed and under capacity.

There has been a few outages lately due to undersea cable failure on a few front.
I'm not sure whether it is the actual cause but there seems to be a failure of the Intra Asia (IA) undersea cable linked to Singapore since June 13. This follows failures on the Asia-Pacific Gateway (APG) and Asia-Africa-Europe-1 (AAE-1) since March 10 and May 23, respectively.

Is there a link to monitor it, or maybe they have some updates on repairs?
